# Error when trying to remove a program

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Can not find script file
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\OFFICEICON.vbs".

This error shows when uninstalling any program. I've been unable to locate a resolution for it. I tried to use:
     "http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/i-get-an-error-message-cant-find-script-engine/9ec39a32-9550-4919-98e0-b5758875efbf" 
    but it did not fix the issue. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: The simplest solution create a blank .vbs file in that location.  But it does not make sense this script would be ran when you attempt to uninstall any program.

Comment: If you have Office installed try a [Repair Install of Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/repair-office-programs-HA010357402.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Source [Fix problems that programs cannot be installed or uninstalled](http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/)

The page contains links to Run Now or Download MS Fixit

> Automatically repair issues that block program installation or removal
>   because of corrupted registry keys.
>
> What it fixes...
>
> - Corrupted registry keys on 64-bit operating systems
> - Corrupted registry keys that control the update data
> - Problems that prevent new programs from being installed
> - Problems that prevent existing programs from being completely uninstalled or updated
> - Problems that block you from uninstalling a program through the Add or Remove Programs (or Programs and Features) item in Control
>     Panel

See also [I get an error message, "can't find script engine Vbscript for script "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\OFFICEICON.vbs"when I try to uninstall a program.](http://www.thewindowshelp.com/question/i-get-an-error-message-can-t-find-script-engine-vbscript-for-script-c-programdata-microsoft-windows-officeicon-vbs-when-i-try-to-uninstall-a-program.html) for more information.

Comment: I've run that but still creates the error.

Comment: @jprichards6914 Have you tried a System Restore?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with OP's question. And Microsoft Fix It usually does not help or make things worse. Most likely it just calls some scripts to do remedy what Microsoft support thinks the problem is